# Insert HTML into page before Javascript is loaded in Chrome/Firefox Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make an extension that adds a certain HTML into a page, however it must be done before any javascript of the page is executed and after the elements are there.

I plan to insert something on the body tag, so using [`"run_at": "document_start"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) makes me unable to add anything to the page as everything is null at that moment.

Comment: *before any javascript of the page is executed and after the elements are there.* This is contradictory. Script tags will generally be executed *immediately* once the HTML parser encounters them, unless they have an `async` or `defer` attribute. This is why some people have problems like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: ...so this question needs more clarification as to the moment, when you need to have your code to intervene.

Comment: The question makes perfect sense as is. All you need here is MutationObserver to wait for the moment when `body` appears. Examples: [one](/a/54812559) - replace `head` with `body`, [two](/a/42013659), [three](/a/39347807)).

Comment: How is this question too broad? I'm asking a single question with a specific problem...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can accomplish this by writing in manifest.json run_at: "document_start" and in my content.js instead of writing to head or body I can use document.documentElement.appendChild.